# Centralizer of a group proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $G$ is a group and $a,x\in G$, prove that $C(x^{-1}ax)=x^{-1}C(a)x$, where $C$ is the centralizer of an element.

I thought inclusion would be the best way to show this.  So let $y\in C(x^{-1}ax).$

Then $y(x^{-1}ax)=x^{-1}axy \Rightarrow xy(x^{-1}ax)=axy\Rightarrow xyx^{-1}a=axyx^{-1}$

From here I see that $a(x^{-1})^{-1}y(x^{-1})=(x^{-1})^{-1}y(x^{-1})a$ But this just shows that $a\in C(x^{-1}yx)$.  How can I show $y\in x^{-1}C(a)x$?  This shows only one way inclusion.  To show equality I need the other direction as well... This seems like the incorrect approach then, or I'm blind to some fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y$ in $x^{-1}C(a)x$ means $xy$ in $C(a)x$ means $xyx^{-1}$ in $C(a)$ means $xyx^{-1}a=axyx^{-1}$ means $xyx^{-1}ax=axy$ means $yx^{-1}ax=x^{-1}axy$ means $y$ in $C(x^{-1}ax)$.

Comment: So I suppose that the proof goes both ways then.  Is that okay to do, go forward and back using the same methods?  what I mean is, proving $C(x^{-1}ax)\subset x^{-1}C(a)x$ first, then using the same steps in reverse $x^{-1}C(a)x \subset C(x^{-1}ax)$?

Comment: "means" means "if and only if".

Comment: That is excellent.  Thank you so much!  I'm happy to see I was getting there, and not completely clueless.  Thank you for helping me finish.